# Impressão direta em Java

Tags: java, impressão, impressora

Durante a execução, o erro abaixo é exibido ao enviar uma `string` para impressora.

```
sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
at sun.print.Win32PrintJob.print(Unknown Source)
```

Código completo

```
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);

    PrintService printService = printServices[5];
    System.out.println(printService.getName());
    DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;


    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();

    value.append("\n\n");
    value.append("\n\tRelação dos Usuários:");

    List<Usuario> usuarios = TapiocariaFacade.listarUsuario();

    int y = 70;

    for(Usuario usuario : usuarios) {

        value.append("\n\tNome: " + usuario.getSenha());
        value.append("\n\tEndereço: " + usuario.getId());
        value.append("\n\tEmail: " + usuario.getEmail());
    }
    System.out.println(value.toString());


    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(value.toString(), docFlavor, null);

    DocPrintJob docPrintJob = printService.createPrintJob();
    try {
        docPrintJob.print(doc, null);
    } catch (PrintException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informe um tipo diferente para seu Flavor para compatibilidade

```
DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
```

---

Voce criou um array com as impressoras porém não existe impressora disponível da posição 5

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);

PrintService printService = printServices[5];
```

Pode tentar com

```
PrintService printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
```

Ou ainda

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);

if (printServices.length==0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Printer Selected");
        }
else if (printServices.length > 0) {
        DocPrintJob pj = printServices[0].createPrintJob();
        {
```

E uma melhor sugestão

```
    PrintService printServices= null;
    DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.STRING.TEXT_PLAIN;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet attr_set =
            new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

    attr_set.add(new Copies(1));           
    attr_set.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);
    PrintService[] service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(docFlavor, attr_set);

    for (int i = 0; i < printServices.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(printServices[i].getName());
        if (printServices[i].getName().equals(nomeDaSuaImpressora)) {
            ps = service[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Por isso, e porque é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui mesmo, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta? Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)

Comment: Ismael bom dia, obrigado por responder mas vamos la, primeiro a impressora na posição 5 ela existe pois  pelo sysout aparece seu nome, vou mudar o Flavor pra ver. Mais tarde eu posto o resultado.

Comment: Ismael, deu certo colocando assim:
   `DocFlavor docFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;`
e criando um arquivo de texto:
`FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/fff.txt");`
Só que no meu caso eu nao queria sempre esta criando um txt mas sim passar uma String direto, alguma ideia?